# pandas select certain rows before and after certain row which meets my criteria

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe.
anywhere in the first row there is an unique value what will meet my criteria.
for instance t = 800

now i want to find the row where that value is in and select from n rows before till n rows after it.

I tried:

```
idx = df[df['t']==stime]
from_idx = idx-1200
to_idx = idx + 1200
vib = df.iloc[to_idx:from_idx]
```

it finds the row which meets my criteria but i cannot get the right selection out of my dataframe

Comment: You want `idx = df[df['t']==stime].index` and you want to reverse your slice range to `vib = df.iloc[from_idx:to_idx]`

Comment: Thanks, and last remark is right of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`idx` in your logic is a `pd.DataFrame` object, not a scalar representing the index for a row. If you extract the scalar index then, assuming your indices are unique, you can use [`pd.Index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) to get the integer positional location:

```
idx = df.index.get_loc(df[df['t'] == stime].index[0])
vib = df.iloc[idx - 1200: idx + 1200]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.