# Find the closest index of the value before and after the specified index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe - record of the stimulation

There i have a column where laser impulses are marked by '1's
And a column where the ECG peaks marked by '1's

[image]

I am trying to come up with an efficient method to find two ecg peaks closest to the laser peak - one before and one after the laser peak

[image]

For me the simplest way seems to be  a 'while' cycle, but maybe there are some pandas functions that can make it more efficiently?

Comment: Check- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820318/pandas-select-certain-rows-before-and-after-certain-row-which-meets-my-criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have the below dataframe to demonstrate:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ECG_peaks':[None, None, None, None, None, 1,    None, None, None, 1, None, None, None, None, 1, None, None, None],
    'Las_peaks':[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 1,    None, None, None, None, 1, None, None, None, None, None]
})
```

print(df):

```
    ECG_peaks  Las_peaks
0         NaN        NaN
1         NaN        NaN
2         NaN        NaN
3         NaN        NaN
4         NaN        NaN
5         1.0        NaN
6         NaN        NaN
7         NaN        1.0
8         NaN        NaN
9         1.0        NaN
10        NaN        NaN
11        NaN        NaN
12        NaN        1.0
13        NaN        NaN
14        1.0        NaN
15        NaN        NaN
16        NaN        NaN
17        NaN        NaN
```

Now get the indexes of `Las_peaks` where value is 1 as :

```
las_peaks = df.loc[df.Las_peaks==1].index
```

Similarly for ecg_peaks:

```
ecg_peaks = df.loc[df.ECG_peaks==1].index
```

Now I use [`np.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to get the nearest index where each laser peak index can be inserted in ecg peak indexes.

```
searches = [np.searchsorted(ecg_peaks, idx) for idx in las_peaks]
```

Then the result of the ecg indexes with one nearest before and one nearest after can be found as:

```
[(ecg_peaks[max(s-1, 0)], ecg_peaks[s]) for s in searches]
```

For this example input, the output is :

```
[(5, 9), (9, 14)]
```

where 5 is the nearest-before index for laser peak at 7 and 9 is the nearest-after index for laser peak at 7.

Similarly 9, 14 for 12th laser index.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `pd.IntervalIndex()` and `get_indexer()`

```
ecg = df['ECG_peaks'].dropna().index
las = df['Las_peaks'].dropna().index

idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(([(ecg[i],ecg[i+1]) for i in range(len(ecg)-1)]))

list(idx[idx.get_indexer(las)].to_tuples())
```

or using `pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks()`

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(df['ECG_peaks'].dropna().index)

idx[idx.get_indexer(df['Las_peaks'].dropna().index)].to_tuples().tolist()
```

or creating a new series and reindexing

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(df['ECG_peaks'].dropna().index)

pd.Series(idx.to_tuples(),index = idx).reindex(df['Las_peaks'].dropna().index).tolist()
```